# Why is my LDAP query failing?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

On my development machine I have a series of VM's.  One of which is a domain controller.  The domain controller is indeed working because I cannot login to other VM's without authenticating to it.

I am trying to test an LDAP query against this DC and it keeps failing

**MY DOMAIN CONTROLLER TREE LOOKS LIKE:**

- DC Machine Name `= ESDEV-DC01`
- Active Directory Name = `ESDEV.COM`
- Canonical Name of Target Node = `ESDEV.COM/Users`

**MY SUBTREE TARGETS LOOK LIKE:**

- Attribute Name = objectCategory
- Attribute Value = CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ESDEV,DC=COM

**MY PARAMETERS ARE:**

- DirectoryPath = `"LDAP://OU=Users, DC=ESDEV-DC01,DC=ESDEV,DC=Com"`
- SearchFilter = `"(&(objectCategory=Person))"`

**QUESTIONS:**

I keep getting "there is no such object on the server".

1. Does this mean it is finding the server directory?
2. Why is the query failing?
3. Is the LDAP query case sensitive?

**MY CONSOLE APP CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

I think my question can be answered without this piece, but for those who care about the code I am using to test the query...

```
namespace LDAPQueryTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string directoryPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryPath"];
                string searchFilter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchFilter"];

                DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(directoryPath);
                DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);

                srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

                if (searchFilter.Length > 0)
                {
                    srch.Filter = searchFilter;
                }

                SearchResultCollection res = srch.FindAll();

                if (res.Count <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your query did NOT return results");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your query returned results");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, Could anyone help?

Comment: @Nayef The answer I marked worked for me.  If this fix isn't working for you...I suggest posting a question for you issue.

Comment: I did, I would apprechate if have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345306/move-object-to-an-ou-in-active-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, the `Users` is a generic container - not an OU - so you should try this LDAP path:

```
LDAP://CN=Users,DC=ESDEV-DC01,DC=ESDEV,DC=Com
```

Note: `CN=Users` instead of `OU=Users`.

And the `LDAP` prefix **MUST** be in all uppercase

But if you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, I would recommend to look at the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which makes a lot of things a lot easier to use!

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ESDEV.COM", "CN=Users, DC=ESDEV-DC01,DC=ESDEV,DC=Com"))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.