# Move Object to an OU in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, ou

I want to move a computer object to another OU I am connected to another domain and I always getting an exception of type ComException **`"A referral was returned from the server"`** and the object never move!

```
        try
        {
            //I get the exception here
            computerObject.MoveTo(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=someOU,OU=parentOU,DC=test,DC=com"));
            computerObject.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException inOp)
        {
            //log 
        }
        catch (COMException comEx)
        {
            //log 
        }

        //joinPath.Close();
        finally
        {
            computerObject.Close();
        }
```

for troubleshooting I changed the code a little bit but again it doesn't work.

```
computerObject.MoveTo(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=someOU,OU=parentOU,DC=test,DC=com"),
                      "admin@test.com","somepassowrd",AuthenticationTypes.Secure));
```

the new exception is of type ComException **`"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."`** 
I checked that there exists an OU in the active directory and I have enough permissions.

I followed Microsoft docs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180856(v=vs.90).aspx 
and many stackoverflow questions.

**Update:** I am running my application in one domain and making changes in *another domain*, it might be the cause of the problem

Comment: Can you connect to that ldap server with the IP address instead of the name. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Comment: @rene I am connected to the ldap server and I am able to search for objects and show them, but when I want to move it, the exception is thrown. I read the article in code project but I could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published my code in the same domain and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis in this method:

`computerObject.MoveTo(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=someOU,OU=parentOU,DC=test,DC=com"),"admin@test.com","somepassowrd",AuthenticationTypes.Secure));`

it should be

`computerObject.MoveTo(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=someOU,OU=parentOU,DC=test,DC=com","admin@test.com", "somepassowrd", AuthenticationTypes.Secure));`

This would certainly explain the exception, I'm surprised you debugger didn't catch it, unless you are writing it freehand, or maybe you mis-typed it into your question?